# How do I show multiple accounts in Windows Mail's sidebar?

Tags: windows-10, windows-mail

How do I show more than one account's links to Inbox, Sent Items, Draft and etc in Windows 10 Mail's left sidebar like Mozilla Thunderbird's sidebar as shown below? 
[image: Mozilla Thunderbird's sidebar]

Answer (score 0):

Click on the wheel in the lower left corner and select 'accounts' . Now add one.

Comment: I already Added multiple accounts, just that I don't like how I have to keep clicking on "Accounts" to switch email accounts! http://i.imgur.com/aLhgEdp.png